# Play videos in an Android game using Processing

Tags: android, video, processing, android-videoview

I am developing an Android game using Processing and my game has a few videos that I need to play. I have tried APWidgets but it takes a path from the SD card, whereas I want to give a path to my assets folder (data folder in Processing). I have also tried the Android VideoView class but I can't find a way to give it a path to my assets folder. Can anyone help me?

Comment: highlight pieces of code and use bold to show where it is in yrou question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that APWidgets is suitable for you. Although it takes a path, it can take any path if granted permissions. You should grant the Android permission and try again.